# Open ajax jstree results in popup window

Tags: javascript, ajax, popup, jstree

Ok, so I spent a lot of time getting jstree to open in a dialog box upon a successful ajax call. Now they want a popup window instead. Seems like it should be easy, but my window gives a 404 error. I'm using Grails, btw. Here's the current code (re-typing, so forgive any syntax errors):

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'resultsView/viewAsdf'
    traditional: true,
    data: {
        documentID: contentID
    },
    success: function (data) {
        var data1 = {'data':data}
        var $genericDialog = $("#genericDialog");
        $genericDialog.jstree({
            "html_data": data1
            [snip]
        }),
        $genericDialog.dialog({
            title: "ASDF"
            modal: true,
            height: 700,
            width: 450,
            buttons: {
                "OK": function() {$genericDialog.dialog("close");}
            }
        });
    }
});
```

So now my question is how do I substitute a window for what's currently the dialog box? What would the url of the window be, since I've already called the url in the ajax method?